# matplotlib date formatting from UTC millisecond

Tags: datetime, matplotlib, datetime-format

I have quote data of forex currencies which I am trying to plot using matplotlib.

I can plot the data but the dates on the x-axis are in milliseconds and do not help.

I have managed to convert the dates to a datetime format, but it comes out as follows :

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 2, 0)
```

When i try run my code I get the following error:

```
line 804, in _candlestick
xy=(t - OFFSET, lower),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is basically the following:

```
quotes = [dates, open, highest, low, close, volume]

ax = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (1, 0), rowspan=6, colspan=4, facecolor='#FFFFFF')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

MOCHLV = zip(quotes[0], quotes[1], quotes[2], quotes[3], quotes[4], quotes[5])


matplotlib.finance.candlestick_ohlc(ax, MOCHLV, width=1.9, colorup='#53c156', colordown='#ff1717')

plt.ylabel('BTC/USD')
plt.xlabel('Date Hours:Minutes')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I found the answer here after some searching. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25224294/8023922